# Number of causes in Porphyry

Tags: reference-request, ancient-philosophy

Aristotle proposed a well known and much studied doctrine of Four causes. Seneca the Younger in the first years of the new era  wrote that  [*his quintam Plato adicit exemplar, quam ipse idean vocat*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Sen.+Ep.+65&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0080) (as a fifth Plato adds the paradigm which he calls "idea"[(Ep.65.7)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius/Letter_65) and there is no lack of suggestions where he might have picked this view (see. eg. Lowenstam,
Mem. Am. Academy in Rome, Vol. 43/4 (1998/9), p.63-78).  As Karamanolis  noted (*Plato and Aristotle in agreement*, Oxf. 2006, p.273 n.92)  "Later Platonists, probably drawing from Porphyry or an intermediary source, attribute to Plato six causes, three main ones (final, paradigmatic, efficient) and three auxiliary ones (synaitia: organic, formal, material)."

Are there cues that Porphyry himself still sticked to Five as the number of causes, having discarded one of the original four and added two ?

Comment: [Kraemer's Philosophy in the Renaissance of Islam, p. 92](https://books.google.com/books?id=O9QUAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=porphyry+%22six+causes%22&source=bl&ots=_ZmoKrkACa&sig=ACfU3U2nBxEhYLsQN2uh-u0Xjiww54jxPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNpcn7vbfrAhUQcq0KHT-aBCAQ6AEwBnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=porphyry%20%22six%20causes%22&f=false) mentions Theiler's *Vorbereitung des Neuplatonismus*, p. 20 for "Porphyry on this subject".